# Update Rule in Temporal difference

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, markov-models, temporal-difference

**The update rule TD(0) Q-Learning:**

`Q(t-1) = (1-alpha) * Q(t-1) + (alpha) * (Reward(t-1) + gamma* Max( Q(t) ) )`

Then take either the current best action (to optimize) or a random action (to explorer)

Where MaxNextQ is the maximum Q that can be got in the next state...

**But in TD(1) I think update rule will be:**

`Q(t-2) = (1-alpha) * Q(t-2) + (alpha) * (Reward(t-2) + gamma * Reward(t-1) + gamma * gamma * Max( Q(t) ) )`

**My question:**
The term `gamma * Reward(t-1)` means that I will always take my best action at `t-1` .. which I think will prevent exploring.. 
Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: So when you say TD(2) you are looking to choose actions based on the next two steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about "eligibility traces" usage, right?
See the [equations and the algorithm](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node78.html).

Notice the **e_t(s, a)** equation there. No penalty is applied when using an exploration step.